# Cant initialize class properly

Tags: python, class

My Initialize should work due to my class being created but I am getting a Syntax problem when I run it.I shouldn't have an indent problem but it keeps erroring on my variable dont know what else to do im new. [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MvQH.png)

Comment: Your class statement has no body.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The code you have posted has an empty class body, but the code in your screenshot does not, so it must have some other problem. You need to post code that reproduces the problem you are having, and describe the error in detail.

Comment: Then go by the error image then

Comment: You're missing a `)` in the `self.sigmoid(...` line.

Comment: AH that may cause it

Answer (score 2):

A class body's can't be empty. You need something there, even if it's just a `pass` statement:

```
class NeuralNetwork():
    pass # Here!

neural_network = NeuralNetwork()
```

Comment: I added an image to show the whole code because the problem lies with the variable